# Add Azure AD users to SharePoints groups and document library permissions in bulk

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, azure-ad, powershell-script

I need to create Azure AD users in bulk (about 90), in order to add each of them:

- To a SharePoint group present in 90 sub-sites
- Authorizations from two libraries in each of these sub-sites

Example :

- User: "user1@mydomain.com"
- SharePoint sub-site: "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/principalsite/sub-site1"
  (already created)
- Two document libraries: "Library1" and "Library2" (already created) for which the user "user1@mydomain.com" must be added to the
  authorizations of these two libraries, with a specific authorization
  level "Special authorization" (already created)

  ---
- User: "user2@mydomain.com"
- SharePoint sub-site: "https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/principalsite/sub-site2" (already created)
- Two document libraries: "Library1" and "Library2" (already created)
  for which the user "user2@mydomain.com" must be added to the authorizations of these two libraries, with a specific authorization level "Special authorization" (already created)

Etc Etc Etc..... Up to 90.

The idea would be to create a PowerShel script based on a CSV file with the necessary information:
UPN > Sharepoint link > Sharepoint group name > Document library names > Name of the specific authorization level.

I don't really master scripting and I don't know much about the powershell functions related to Sharepoint.
After some research, I find information but it doesn't really correspond to my needs.

Can you help me ?

Regards,

Comment: Hello,

I share my research  : 

Mass creation of Azura AD users:
$users = Import-Csv C:\O365_EA_Users.csv
$users | ForEach-Object {
New-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.UserPrincipalName -DisplayName $_.DisplayName -FirstName $_.FirstName -LastName $_.LastName -Password $_.Password }

Adding these users to the "Visitors" groups of each sub-site:
$users = Import-Csv C:\O365_EA_UsersToGroupSP_2.csv
$users | ForEach-Object {
Add-SPOUser - Site $_.Subsite -LoginName $_.UserPrincipalName -Group $_.Group }

Anyone to help me add users to document library permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can already create the users and add them to groups, why not create a group in the permissions for each document library with the "Special auth" permissions level, and add the user to that group?

Answer (score 0):

Having integrated users into the visitor group of each sub-site, I ended up adding this group to the permissions of the two document libraries of each sub-site (there is obviously no powershell function to add users, only groups, and thinking about it, it is wise to proceed like that for future evolution in permissions)

```
$group = Import-Csv C:\O365_EA_GrouptoPermissionList.csv

$group | ForEach-Object {
Connect-PnPOnline $_.url -Credential $userCred;
Set-PnPGroupPermissions -identity $_.groupname -List $_.library1 -AddRole "MySpecialPermission";
Set-PnPGroupPermissions -identity $_.groupname -List $_.library2 -AddRole "MySpecialPermission"
 }
```